# selecting an element not highlighting the actual element position in remote debugging of samsung galaxy S5

Tags: css-selectors

When I try to remotely debug a Samsung galaxy S5 device and hover on a particular element using the selector it does not highlight the exact position of the element but it highlights somewhere else which is hindering the Automation testing.
Has anyone faced the same issue and has any solution?

[Screenshot attached for logon button highlight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSY0x.jpg)

Comment: How do i add inline image....It goes for link everytime?

Comment: I dont have 10 reputation to post the image as this is a new account.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the issue further and found the solution.
The issue was because of the **Zoom:0.7** for the  tag for resolution below 640px.
Once I changed the same to "1" I was able to focus the pointer at the correct position.